# The Url of dialog box does not work with angular.bootstrap (infinite $digest Loop)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, office-js, angularjs-digest

I have a mean-stack website. I want to use [ExecuteFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428344/702977) to bind a button to launch this website in a Dialog box:

```
function doSomethingAndShowDialog(event) {
    clickEvent = event;
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:3000/try", {}, function () {})
}
```

Clicking on the button opens a dialog box with the following url, it does show the content of the page:

```
https://localhost:3000/try?_host_Info=excel|web|16.00|en-us|7fe9b4e9-d51e-bea5-d194-c817bc5ed4bc|isDialog#%2Ftry%3F_host_Info=excel%7Cweb%7C16.00%7Cen-us%7C7fe9b4e9-d51e-bea5-d194-c817bc5ed4bc%7CisDialog
```

However, in the console, there are [Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) at `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp'])`:

```
var wait = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']) 
        console.log("bootstrapped inside Office.initialize");
        clearTimeout(wait);
    })
}

function myFunction () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']) 
        console.log("bootstrapped outside Office.initialize");
    })
}

app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.config(...);
app.controller(...);
```

If we just open `https://localhost:3000/try` in a browser, there is no error.

Does anyone know why that long url did not work with `angular.bootstrap`? How could we fix this?

**Edit 1:** a screenshot of the console for `https://localhost:3000/try?_host_Info=excel...`. Note that neither `bootstrapped inside Office.initialize` nor `bootstrapped outside Office.initialize` is displayed. But If I run `https://localhost:3000/try` in a browser, I will only see `bootstrapped outside Office.initialize`, when I call it from an Excel client, I will only see `bootstrapped inside Office.initialize`.

[image]

Comment: You should call angular.bootstrap() after you've loaded or defined your modules.Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap or more details.

Comment: Where is `'myapp'` declared?

Comment: You are calling `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']) ` twice check it. You need to bootstrap it one time.

Comment: Guys, because of `setTimeout`, I can bootstrap either inside or outside `Office.initialize`, so `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp'])` will always be executed one time. In the code, the declaration of `myapp` is written after the bootstrap block, but my tests show that the written order is not that important...

Comment: Actually, I think you are calling it twice. Both Office.init and myFunction wire up to the Document.Ready event. As soon as that event fires, both of those callbacks will be triggered.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT please see my update, neither `bootstrapped inside Office.initialize` nor `bootstrapped outside Office.initialize` is displayed for `https://localhost:3000/try?_host_info...`. `setTimeout` could make sure `bootstrap` is called once for `https://localhost:3000/try`, how come it did not work with `https://localhost:3000/try?_host_info...`

Comment: @SoftTimur , you are calling it twice because  `inside Office initialize ` will be called as it a javascript function expression and your  `SetTimeOut` method will also be calling again after wait time. Now answering your question why not with `https://localhost:3000/try` because it is no where releated to the Office.initalize method so that is the reason bootstrap will be done only once in that particular case

Comment: @Webruster It is `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` which added systematically `?_host_Info=excel|...` to the url... Do you know how to disable this?

Comment: @SoftTimur systematically means , on where it would be adding and just want to be sure that are you using Jquery any where?

Comment: @SoftTimur after a bit of investigation i went a bit deeper i went to that [execution function](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example) and there that repo is using the Jquery internally so the reason for your infinite digest loop is that `$` the same is used by the `angular` and also `Jquery` so `angular` things it as its own function . one way to mitigate this issue is that you can fork that repo and try to change the `$` to `jQuery` and test to load it . its worth to give a try

Comment: @Webruster I tried to use `jQuery(document)` instead of `$(document)`, it still had the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151140/discussion-between-webruster-and-softtimur).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to wire up a page that can operate as either an add-in or a stand-alone page. Whenever possible it is best to maintain separate views for each use case. If nothing else, it makes everything a lot more straight forward. Combining them is likely creating far more overhead and headache that it's worth.

Part of your issue here is that you've got two separate code paths and you're assuming only one path will execute at a time. When loaded in a browser this is true, it will simply ignore the Office.initialize function. When loaded within Office however it will execute both paths. One will be executed by Office, the other will be executed by `setTimeOut` after 1 second.

If you have two distinct code paths where only one is ever executed, you need to test to determine if you're operating as an add-in or as a standalone page. This is where those query parameters come into play. If you have a `_host_Info` query parameter defined then you're operating within Office. For example:

```js
if (getParameterByName('_hostInfo')) { // _hostInfo is defined
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp'])
            console.log("bootstrapped inside Office.initialize");
        });
    }
} 
else { // _hostInfo is not defined
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp'])
        console.log("bootstrapped outside Office.initialize");
    })
}
```

*Note that `getParameterByName()` here is a function pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/105518). You could use any method you prefer however.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I do want to use a function to check if the page is operating as an add-in or as a standalone page. But it seems that I can only use `ui-router` to distinguish `https://localhost:3000/try` and `https://localhost:3000/try?_host_Info...`, and I don't think we can put `angular.bootstrap` inside `$stateProvider.state(...)`, can we?