# Have to wait several minutes before the opening of the dialog for the second time

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have a mean-stack website. I want to use [ExecuteFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428344/702977) to bind a button to launch this website in a Dialog box. Here is my `FunctionFile.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        var clickEvent;
        (function () {
            Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            };
        })();

        function showNotification(text)
        {
            writeToDoc(text);
            clickEvent.completed();
        }

        function doSomethingAndShowDialog(event) {
            clickEvent = event;
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://www.google.com", {}, function () {})
        }

        function writeToDoc(text)
        {
            Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(text,
                function (asyncResult) {
                    var error = asyncResult.error;
                    if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                        console.log("Unable to write to the document: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Function file body is never displayed.
</body>
</html>
```

And in `manifest.xml` I use:

```
<FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />
... ...
<bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/htmls/FunctionFile.html" />
```

I realise that after the loading of the manifest, we could launch the dialog box by clicking on the button. However, after closing the dialog manually and clicking on the button again, we need to **wait several minutes** to see the notification window `... wants to display a new window`. There is no error in the console.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling an external URI from `displayDialogAsync`. This isn't supported and attempting to do so leads to a number of unexpected behaviors.

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync#parameters) regarding `startAddress` must:

> The initial page must be on the same domain as the parent page. After the initial page loads, you can go to other domains.

Comment: I wrote google as an example. initially it was a help page on my domain. I will correct it later.

Comment: Is the page handing office.initialize prior to redirecting?

Comment: The details of the page can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444739/the-url-of-dialog-box-does-not-work-with-angular-bootstrap-infinite-digest-loo)...